# How to hide "Delete Site" link for a user rather than Admin?

Tags: theming

I have website created in Drupal LMS "Openscholar". Its a academy site and there are various,they have there on vsite where they can add content as per there role.When user logged in ,there is a link to "Delete Vsite" available on his/her profile,

[image]

Therefore,my issue is that he can delete his account without concerning Admin.I tried to hide it using `"Display:none"` in CSS but it will hide Delete link for admin too. Thus, i want to know how to resolve such issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by using a condition in your code. If current user is **admin** then show that **Delete Link** else hide it.

```
global $user;
if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles){
  your code to show link
}
```

Comment: why you use user_load function if you define global user already

Comment: ya, its right @Adi

Comment: how to add css property "Display:none" within such code ?

Comment: if you are trying code then no need of adding "Display:none;". If you want add Display:none then give it as inline or as in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $global $user
    //Get admin_id from database and add condition
    if ($admin_id == $user->uid){
         add your code here 
         }
```

Hope this idea of code is helpful for you

Comment: can i do the same for a user other than Admin ? Moreover, can i add css to in this custom code ? One more thing where to add this code i.e in which file ?

Comment: yes you can use for everyone user ,create custom module then place or add this code in page.tpl.php (its not good way)

Comment: how to use css within this code ?

Comment: If we have more than 1 admin, $admin_id will become error or become more complicated. Use abin's answer